# SQL Query not working as it should

Tags: sql, python-2.7, sqlite, left-join

So I have three tables:

```
authors:
--------
ID    Name
1     John
2     Sue
3     Mike

authors_publications:
---------------------
AuthorID    PaperID
1            1
1            2
2            2
3            1
3            2
3            3

publications:
-------------
ID         year
1          2004
2          2005
3          2004
```

I'm trying to join them so that I count the number of publications each author has had on 2004. If they didn't publish anything then it should be zero

ideally the result should look like this:

```
ID    Name    Publications_2004
 1    John           1
 2    Sue            0
 3    Mike           2
```

I tried the following:

```
select a.ID, Name, count(*) as Publications_2004 
from authors_publications as ap left join authors as a on ap.AuthorID=a.ID left join publications as p on p.ID=ap.PaperID 
where year=2004 
group by ap.AuthorID
```

I don't understand why it's not working. Its completely removing any authors that haven't published in 2004.

Comment: You have authors on the wrong side of the LEFT join.   Try joining in this order:   authors LJ authors_publications LJ publications.

Comment: @TabAlleman i originally had it that way and it didn't work, so I tried switching it and it gave me the same result. I'm wondering if it could be because I'm dealing with 3 tables?

Comment: Actually it's because you have "WHERE year=2004".   Try moving this filter to the ON clause of the JOIN to publications.

Comment: @Randy it is my understanding that LEFT JOIN is equivalent to LEFT OUTER JOIN. And sqlite3 doesn't support FULL OUTER JOIN if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WHERE statement is taking the result set returned from the JOIN's and them trimming off records where `year<>2004`.

To get around this you can do a few different things

You can apply a filter to the publications table in the `ON` statement when joining. This will filter the results before joining

```
 SELECT a.ID,
    NAME,
    count(*) AS Publications_2004
FROM authors_publications AS ap
LEFT JOIN authors AS a
    ON ap.AuthorID = a.ID
LEFT JOIN publications AS p
    ON p.ID = ap.PaperID AND
        p.year = 2004
GROUP BY ap.AuthorID
```

You could use a case statement instead of a WHERE:

```
SELECT a.ID,
    NAME,
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.year = 2004 THEN 1 ELSE 0) END AS Publications_2004
FROM authors_publications AS ap
LEFT JOIN authors AS a
    ON ap.AuthorID = a.ID
LEFT JOIN publications AS p
    ON p.ID = ap.PaperID 
GROUP BY ap.AuthorID, NAME
```

You could use a subquery to pre-filter the publications table to only 2004 records, which is just explicitly doing what was implicit in the first option:

```
SELECT a.ID,
    NAME,
    count(*) AS Publications_2004
FROM authors_publications AS ap
LEFT JOIN authors AS a
    ON ap.AuthorID = a.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM publications WHERE AND year = 2004) AS p
    ON p.ID = ap.PaperID 
GROUP BY ap.AuthorID, NAME
```

Also, because you are not aggregating `NAME` with a formula, you should add that to your `GROUP BY` otherwise you may get funky results.